# Big O of two functions

Tags: php, performance, optimization, big-o

I have been programming in PHP for a long time now, and as I don't come from a computer science / math background I only have a basic understanding of the `Big O` notation, so I have taken a function and tried to improve it and express them both in Big O:

**Example 1**

```
function foo($j) {
    $ids = array();
    while (count($ids) < $j) {
        $id = gen_id();  // assume this function will return you an integer
        if (!in_array($id, $ids)) {
            $ids[] = $id;
        }
    }
    return $ids;
}
```

I would improve this function by removing the while loop for `count($ids)` and replace with `for`loop So that `count($ids)` doesn't have to be evaluated every time in the loop, and also replace `is_array` with `isset` and move the values to keys (`isse`t is quicker than `in_array`)

**Example 2 - Improved**

```
function foo($j) {
    $ids = array();
    for($i = 1; $i<= $j; ++$j) {
        $id = gen_id();  // assume this function will return you an integer
        if (!isset($ids[$id])) {
            $ids[$id] = true;
        }
        else {
            --$i;
        }
    }
    return $ids;
}
```

I would express the above functions with the following Big O Notation:

**Example 1:** O(n^2), **Example 2:** O(n)

Am I correct with my notations? Is there a better way still to do the same function?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: First, have you determined that this method needs to be optimized in the first place?  Second, the correct notation would be `O(n)` for both (constant factors are irrelevant in Big O notation).

Comment: You probably meant `++$i` in the second `for` loop.

Comment: yup it should've been $i.. but --$i;

Comment: @Lizard I've rewrote your function in a more concise manner and posted it as an answer. I do not think you will be able to achieve a more efficient result than my answer. `:)`

Comment: Thanks! This is really making sense now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would write that function in a more straightforward approach: The inner `for` loop is the perfect scenario for a `do ... while` loop.

```
function foo( $j)
{
    $ids = array();
    for( $i = 0; $i < $j; $i++)
    {
        do
        {
            $id = gen_id();
        } while( isset( $ids[$id]));
        $ids[$id] = true;
    }
    return $ids;
}
```

**Edit:** Actually, this function is `O($j)` / `O(n)`, since `gen_id()` and `isset()` are both constant `O(1)` (`isset()` is a hash table lookup). So, the inner efficiency of the `for` loop is constant time `O(1)`, making the whole function `O(n)`.

Comment: I am aware that isset is a hashtable looklup and therefore O(1). Is it the for loop that makes it O(n)?

Comment: Yes, the for loop is what makes it O(n) since it (the for loop) must make n iterations to generate n IDs.

Comment: Thanks, this is starting to be more clear now... but either way the 2nd function is quicker even though both are O(n) as example 1 has O(n) + O(n) and the 2nd is O(n) + O(1)?

Comment: The first is actually `O(n^2)`, since the while loop will execute n times, and the call to `in_array` is a linear search, making the code inside the while loop `O(n)`, so it is `O(n) * O(n) = O(n^2)`.

Comment: Thanks! This is really making sense now!

Comment: @Lizard: Big-O notation isn't exactly a measure of how quickly a function will run. Two different functions may both be `O(f(n))`, but the first could run in a few seconds on a given computer, while the other could take years. Also, an `O(n)` function may be slower than a `O(n*n)` function for some (usually small) inputs; eventually, the `O(n)` function will overtake the `O(n*n)` function, but it may only happen for inputs of astronomical size.

Comment: ...  Big-O describes the overall complexity of a function. It tells you the upper bound on the overall time (or memory; you can use Big-O notation for memory usage, though note a given algorithm can have different time and space complexities) requirements of a function; how those requirements grow as the problem size grows. There are other notations (e.g. Big-Ω, Big-Θ) that deal with other bounds.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: constant coefficients don't matter in Big O notation, which means `O(n) = O(cn)` for any constant `c != 0`.

For the 1st one, I know `count($ids)` takes `O(1)` time to evaluate, but how about `in_array($id, $ids)`? I don't know exactly. But if it's `O(n)` or `O(logn)`, then the whole would be `O(n^2)` or `O(nlogn)`. I don't think this could be implemented in `O(1)` time, which could give an `O(n)` time for the whole function.

For the 2nd one, this is `O(n)` and seemingly faster than the 1st one.

**EDIT:** I just think wikipedia has described [the big O notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) somehow clearly. Go and read some.

Comment: FYI `in_array` is `O(n)` as it performs a linear search.

Answer (score 1):

Your thinking is good but you are not correct.

The following will clarify you....

```
function foo($j) 
{
 for($i=1;$i<j;$i++)
 {
  // some code here
 }
 for($i=1;$i<j;$i++)
 {
 // some code here
 }
}
```

You may think this will be 0(2n) but The constant term does not expressed on 0 notation. So
It has complexity 0(n).

Look the following

```
 function foo($j) 
{
 for($i=1;$i<j;$i++)
 {
    for($k=1;$k<i;$k++)
    {
     // some code here
    }
 }

}
```

It has the complexity 0(n^2).

Answer (score 1):

```
for ($i=0;$i<$j; ) {
  $id = gen_id();
  if (!isset($ids[$id])) {
    $ids[$id]=true;
    $i++;
  }
}
```